# python re.search with optional parameter

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to find a substring with this pattern: `.*(_\d+)?`

Example:

```
abc_4
abc_345
abc
```

Just one regular string, followed by an optional "_", followed by at least one digit.

But when I use:

```
re.search("(.*)(_\d+)?" , str).group(1)
```

it always returns the entire string.

Comment: Look up regular expression greediness.

Comment: Can the input be `abc_def_123` (with more than one `_` character)?

Comment: be more specific with what you don't want to capture before your digits....`\w`.

Comment: Just one regular string, followed by "_", followed by at least one digit

Comment: `followed by at least one digit` then last string `abc` won't match

Comment: @anubhava I think he means "optionally followed by ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `*` is greedy, it tries to match the longest possible string, so long as the rest of the regexp can match. Since the part after `_` is optional, `.*` can gobble it up, since the rest of the regexp can match an empty string.

Change `.*` to `[^_]*` so that it can't match the underscore before the number.

```
([^]*)(_\d+)?
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of `(.*)` use `[^_]*?` to stop at the first `_` character.

Comment: No need for the `?`. `[^_]*` will stop at the first `_` character whether it's greedy or not.

Answer (score 1):

You have made the `_nnn` part optional (`?`), so the `.*` is matching the whole string always (greedy). Make it non-greedy:

```
.*?(_\d+)?
```